# VSCode doesn't close child processes (processChild.js)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, nvm

I've just noticed that VSCode doesn't close the Node.js child process after closing the debugger as the way it should be. Those processes seriously start to eat my memory after 5-10 start/stop of the debugger.

I'm using the latest LTS nodejs with the management of [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

I don't know if something wrong with my debugger configuration or VSCode bug but here is my configuration;

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch via yarn",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "dev"
      ],
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "pwa-node"
    },
    {
      "name": "Node Attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "request": "attach",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "pwa-node"
    },
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "reAttach": true,
      "name": "Launch firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "webpack://_n_e/pages/news",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/pages/news"
        },
        {
          "url": "webpack://_n_e/client/index.tsx",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/pages/news/index.tsx"
        },
        {
          "url": "webpack://_n_e/pages/haberler",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/pages/haberler"
        },
        {
          "url": "webpack://_n_e/components",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/components"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Combined debugger",
      "configurations": ["Launch via yarn", "Node Attach", "Launch firefox"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the problem occurs only if `Launch via yarn` closed before the closing `Node Attach`.

To prevent a mistake with the order of closing I've removed the `Node Attach` configuration in favor of the [Auto Attach](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach) feature.

Here is the latest version of my configuration for who needs it;

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch via yarn",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "dev"
      ],
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "reAttach": true,
      "name": "Launch firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "webpack://_n_e/client/index.tsx",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/pages/index.tsx"
        },
        {
          "url": "webpack://_n_e/components",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}/components"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Combined debugger",
      "configurations": ["Launch via yarn", "Launch firefox"]
    }
  ]
}
```